# PostgreSQL logical replication and partition table

Tags: postgresql, replication, partitioning, postgresql-11

We have a large database and we want a copy of the database in our company for faster access. we are going to achieve this copy by logical replication on PostgreSQL 11.
But we have a big problem.
We have a table with more than 800M rows, for better performance we've decided to partition the table.
We create a partition table with the same name on the origin database table but we got bellow error on subscription creation :

```
ERROR:  logical replication target relation "public.MY_TABLE" is not a table
```

- At first, do you suggest logical replication for this purpose? could you please give pros and cons on logical replication instead of other approaches.
- Is there any solution to replicate a table in partition table or we have to replicate in a normal table and for example we write a job to move data from the table to partitioned table nightly!

Comment: Why did partitioning solve your performance problem in the first place? Can you explain?

Comment: This is the BI DB. because our queries are base on day, so we portion the table by day. we have a near 3M rows per day, so partitioning by day let us have better performance in

Comment: This is a limitation in PG 11, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53554727/logical-replication-and-declarative-partitioning-in-postgresql-11 Can't you base your logical replication on the base table?

Comment: Is the original table not partitioned at all?  You say you want a copy "in our company", but where is the original?  Is it also in your company, or is it someplace else?

Comment: The original one is connected to an application and It is not partitioned. also, the origin is in somewhere else, in another country.